# Inequality regarding complex numbers.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $x∈S^1$ and $a∈B$, where $S^1=\{z∈\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ and $B$ denote the open disc in the complex field with centre $0$ and radius $1$. Let $M=x(\frac{z-a}{1-āz})$ for $z$ in $B$. Then show that $|M|<1$ if $|z|<1$. Here conjugate of $a$ is denoted by $ā$.

My attempt: Since $x∈S^1$ then $|x|=1$ and $a∈B$ then $|a|<1$ as $B$ is an open disc. Then $|M|=|x||\frac{z-a}{1-āz}|$. This implies $|M|=|\frac{z-a}{1-āz}|$. So, it is enough to show that $|\frac{z-a}{1-āz}|<1$ whenever $|z|<1$. But I failed to prove this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This is certainly **not** true when $a=1,x=1$.  What are the restrictions on $a$?

Comment: @saulspatz. $a$ can't be $1$, as $a$ belongs to a disk which is open with radius $1$ and centre $0$. So $|a|<1$, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that before, even when I looked for it.

Comment: It's the maximum modulus principle, I think.  Note that $(z-a)/(1-\overline az)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $S^1$.  On the boundary the modulus is $1$.  (Multiply numerator and denominator by $\overline z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|M| \le \left|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right| = \left|\frac{\bar z}{\bar z}\cdot \frac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right| = |\bar z| \left|\frac{z-a}{\bar z - \bar a}\right| = |\bar z| < 1$$